# C++ Why does the compiler not accept this function

Tags: c++

This is my prototype:

```
int WordCount(wstring u, int uLCID);
```

And this is in the cpp file:

```
int WordCount(wstring u, int uLCID);
{
//accept anything for uLCID... meaning we don't process it
int b = 0;
int iCount=0;
for(;;)
{
    int n = u.find(L" ",b);

    if (n>-1)
    {
        iCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    b=(n+1);
}
return iCount;
}
```

The compiler tells me:

`A declaration was expected.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because

```
int WordCount(wstring u, int uLCID);
{                                  ^
                                   ^
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 7):

You have an extra semicolon here:

```
int WordCount(wstring u, int uLCID);
{
```

Answer (score 2):

When you place a semicolon `;` at the end of a function you are declaring a prototype as you did above.  Doing so again when you intended a definition will yield the error you received.  Be careful when `copy-paste` a prototype so as to avoid this in the future.